# Delphi - How can I extract the digits from a character string?

Tags: regex, string, delphi

I was developing a program that validate a CPF, a type of document of my country. I already did all the math. But in the input Edit1, the user will insert like:

```
123.456.789-00
```

I have to get only the numbers, without the hyphen and the dots, to my calcs worth.

I'm newbie with Delphi, but I think that's simple. How can I do that? Thanks for all

Comment: Perhaps, `TRegEx.Replace(s, '\D', '')`? (`\D` is a non-digit, and `\W` is a non-word character, both should work).

Comment: Loop through the string picking out the digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
text := '123.456.789-00'
text := TRegEx.Replace(text, '\D', '')
```

Here, `\D` matches any non-digit symbol that is replaced with an empty string.

Result is `12345678900` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT9qT0/1)).

Answer (score 2):

Using David's suggestion, iterate your input string and remove characters that aren't numbers.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function GetNumbers(const Value: string): string;
var
  ch: char;
  Index, Count: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Value));
  Count := 0;      
  for Index := 1 to length(Value) do
  begin
    ch := Value[Index];
    if (ch >= '0') and (ch <='9') then
    begin
      inc(Count);
      Result[Count] := ch;
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(Result, Count);
end;

begin
  Writeln(GetNumbers('123.456.789-00'));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Be nice to avoid as many of those heap allocations as you can.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Not meaning to be obtuse, but I'm curious about what you have in mind regarding "Be nice ...".  Do you meant counting the number of digit occurrences first, then allocating space for the Result based on that, or what?

Comment: @Martyn That. Or allocate string of same length as result, populate, and size before exit. Two heap allocs.

Comment: @John Also worth pointing out that `in` with Unicode text will lead to warnings. I'd use `(ch >= '0') and (ch <= '9')`

Comment: Yes. I corrected the off by one error. I'd still reduce the heap allocs were it me, but perhaps I'm being picky.

Comment: No. Short strings are long deprecated, don't support Unicode, limited in length. I edited in what I meant.